# inserting with linq

Tags: c#, linq, insert, types

i am trying to insert a load of data into a table with linq
the data arrives in a nameValueCollection with the  key as the column name and the value as the value to be inserted

i need to convert all the values to their correct datatype but cant think of a good way to do this and then insert
i can iterate over the columns in the LINQ'ed table

```
        TransactionDataContext db = new TransactionDataContext();

        var columns = db.Mapping.MappingSource
                .GetModel(typeof(TransactionDataContext))
                .GetMetaType(typeof(Transaction))
                .DataMembers;

        Type t;
        string typeName, colName;

        Transaction trans = new Transaction();

         for(int i = 0;i<columns.Count();i++)
        {
            if(columns[i].Name.In(nvcRequest.Keys)){
                colName = columnNames[i].Name;
                t =  columnNames[i].Type;
                typeName = t.Name.ToString().ToLower();

               switch(typeName){
               case "int":
            //convert value to int and add it into the new transaction
            //but i cant do t[columns[i]] = newly typed value unfortunately..  - what can i do?
            break;
            case "datetime":
            //convert to datetime and add into the appropriate field in the new transaction
            break;
            }
        }
```

etc..
...
..

db.SubmitChanges();

the In function is :

```
    public static bool In(this object o, IEnumerable c){

        foreach(object i in c){
            if(i.Equals(o))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

any ideas?
maybe i should just build up a string query myself?
i hope not :(

any help much appreciated

nat

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Convert.ChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.changetype.aspx)

Edit:

Based on your comment below, if you have a `Transaction` object, and a `Dictionary<string, object>` with the values and you want to set the properties of the object with the values from the dictionary, you could do

```
foreach (PropertyInfo myPropertyInfo in myTransactionObject.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    myPropertyInfo.SetValue(myTransactionObject,
        Convert.ChangeType(aPropertyValue, myPropertyInfo.PropertyType), 
        null);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i would still have to do 
trans.float_column = convert.changetype(value, typeof(float));

for each of the 45 fields

would really like to be able to loop around the NVC, as there isnt always data in the NVC for every column (the ones that arent always there are nullable in the DB)
to avoid having write lines to check if there is a value, convert it and then finish with the 
trans.colname = converted value
45 times :(

hence the need to do 
trans[string columnname] = convert.changetype(...)

can i do that